# My linux partition has no stable internet connection

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, cinnamon, asus

I have a linksys EA7500 routing my internet to all my devices. On my ASUS N551J I have a dual boot windows/linux mint 18.1 Cinnamon 64-bit.

Only the linux-partition out of all my devices drops internet continuously (I have internet for some minutes, there's never a constant period to this, and then it suddenly drops out. I then reconnect to my 5GHZ connection and back to the 2.4... it drives me crazy.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: What is your WLAN card?

Comment: This is the information after entering -sudo lshw -c network-

Comment: *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-81-generic firmware=17.459231.0 ip=192.168.1.141 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:37 memory:f7900000-f7901fff

Comment: *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.1
       logical name: enp5s0f1
       version: 12
       serial: 08:62:66:b8:66:c7
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits

Comment: Try to disable bluetooth , power management and disable 802.11n see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#iwlwifi